# Transition to current route with different upstream/parent dynamic segment in ember?

Tags: ember.js, dynamic-url

I have a peculiar case.

Say I am on `root.com/product/1/detail`

I want to be able to change the product dynamic segment, but still be in the detail sub route. for example 
`root.com/product/2/detail

And if I am in `root.com/product/1` I want the SAME transition code to go to `root.com/product/2

Normally, you'd put something like `transitionToRoute('product', this.get('id'))`, but that takes me only to the product route. I need the extra flexibility of preserving any sub routes the visitor may currently be in.

Perhaps there is some sort of "currentRoute" property I can hook into like `transitionToRoute('controller.currentRoute', this.get('id'))` while passing in new ids or objects for dynamic segments?

Answer (score 1):

You can set current route using:

```
currentRoute = App.__container__.lookup('controller:application').get('currentPath')
```

Then you should be able to do something along the lines of what you mentioned:

```
transitionToRoute('currentRoute', this.get('id'))
```